# mvn parallel building -T on karaf-services-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, deployment, apache-karaf

I'm trying to execute a parallel build execution on maven with the command

> mvn clean install -DskipTests -T 2.0C

but the artifact org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-services-maven-plugin:4.2.8

provokes this warning

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that have goals not marked   *
[WARNING] * as @threadSafe to support parallel building.                  *
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in myBundle Install:
[WARNING] org.apache.karaf.tooling:karaf-services-maven-plugin:4.2.8
[WARNING] Enable debug to see more precisely which goals are not marked @threadSafe.
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
```

In the karaf jira actually says that is supported version since 3.0.6 version...
so I am lossing some other argument or configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven is indeed correct, the plugin at version [4.2.8](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-4.2.8/tooling/karaf-services-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/tooling/tracker/GenerateServiceMetadata.java) and newer ones are not marked as thread-safe.
Several other mojos from different plugins are tough, so it is most likely not a mistake.

I assume you read that the karaf-maven-plugin is thread-safe, but you are using a different plugin named karaf-services-maven-plugin.

You can try if the build works on parallel execution, but i would not recommend doing so. If required, you could file a feature request.